# How to protect google analytics mobile tracking ID from hacking

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Is there any solution to protect google analytics from receiving fake information from Spammers ? The problem is anybody can send information by knowing tracking id.

I found the following solution, filter domain. But that's for web and how to implement for mobile app ?

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/protect-analytics-from-hacking/

Thanks

Comment: How it will get revealed to anyone ? possibly you can secure by using send box level at development, while going live there should be another ID possibly known by few people only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about google analytics spam which has been talked to death.  And is not programing related.

Comment: @Hasya spammers do not usually target specific ids. The format for the tracking is well documented, so you can randomly create ids and send calls to them (it's not that http calls are expensive or something), a few of them are bound to belong to a real account. Plus, off topic.

Answer (score 1):

### Visible Tracking ID

On a website you can right click, `Show source` but you can't on a mobile application. Therefore your trying ID can't be find from your clients application. Nonetheless, if your code is pushed to a public repository (Github for example) robots may find it.

### Random spammers

Even if your trackingID is kept secret you'll have some bot spamming your account randomly (they try every possible tracking ID). Google added a tool to prevent this: go to `Admin` > `View` > `View settings` > turn on `Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders`. Then Google will automatically filter hits from the known fake domains.

### Hostname security hack

Even with Google's automatic filter you may still see some spam. This can be fixed with what they explain in the link you provided.
In your article they create a `custom dimension` and use it to filter real data from spam data. You can also use this with your mobile application, the thing is, it does not need to be a host name it just need to be a string only known by you, its sort of a new secret added to your tracking ID (which should already be secret).
This works because bots can handle the try of every trackingID but they can't try every `custom dimension` with every possible `value`, it's too much work for them.